# How do I adjust transparency of watermark in Microsoft Word 2010?

Tags: microsoft-word, pictures, watermark, transparency

I added a watermark to my page from

> Page Layout > Watermark > Custom Watermark... > Picture Watermark

However, the resulting watermark was dim and fainted like it is transparent. I want it to look like the original image; as if I inserted it from *Insert > Picture*.

How do I adjust transparency of watermark?

---

Versions:
Office: Microsoft Office Professional Plus 2010
Word: 14.0.6112.5000 (64-bit)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Setting transparency to a picture in Microsoft Word 2007](http://superuser.com/questions/36680/setting-transparency-to-a-picture-in-microsoft-word-2007)

Answer (score 3):

I think the question was related to a Picture Watermark, not a "Word Art" one. When you go to Page Layout>Watermark>Custom Watermark>Picture watermark>Select picture (do it). Set your scale (normally 100%) and make sure washout is UNCLICKED. I hope that's what the problem was That's what made mine looked faded. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Different version of Word? I don't have a tab labeled **Page Layout**.) I get a picture watermark going through the **Insert** tab >**Watermark**. Select the picture option, then click on **Select Picture...** . Choose the picture you want to use as the watermark, then hit **Insert**. Don't click on **Washout**. Click on **OK**. You can always go back to the Watermark menu to adjust the **Scale** if you want. Double click the area at the top of the page (above the first line of text). This will open up the **Header/Footer** function. Double click on the image and this will open up the **Format Picture** window. There you can use the slider to adjust the transparency, and a lot of other cool features. Click **OK** and say to yourself "OK."

Comment: Welcome to Superuser.  Please take the tour at https://superuser.com/Tour to get the most out of this site.

Answer (score 2):

A text watermark will be WordArt. Since you're seeing picture formatting tools, you must have a picture watermark. The **Washout** setting is just a specific brightness setting; you can adjust the brightness to be more or less using the menu under **brightness** in the **Adjust group** on the contextual **Picture Tools** | **Format** tab. If you want something between those settings, right-click on the graphic, choose **Format Picture**, and use the slider or spin box to select a specific percentage.
To get to the **Picture Tools->Format** tab, double-click in on the **Header** or **Footer** space of the page and then select (click on) your watermark picture. You can then edit the Brightness and Contrast to your liking.

Comment: How do you select the image used in the custom watermark and get the Picture Tools contextual tabs to appear? I'm interested in this question too because it doesn't seem like I can get much control over the watermark.

Comment: as explained above, you do that by entering the footer/header areas and from there you will be able to select the watermak picture, right click on it and select shape/picture tools. just tried it out in MS Office Word 2016